# How to copy video files from gallery into internal storage?

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I copy a video opened by the gallery to my app's internal storage?
I'm using Android +10, so I am not able to see the absolute path of the video.
All I have is this URI: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F29/ORIGINAL/NONE/1233865568

Comment: You can just open an InputStream for that uri and open a FileOutputStream for a file in internal storage and then copy from one stream to the other as usual. The same as with a 'normal' file copy.

Comment: Could you please post an example of the code, please?